# Converting XAML to XBAP

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I have already created a project using WPF Application and it is running smoothly but now i am requested to change it into Browser based project. For this i consulted the web and developed the WCF service for the data communication. Currently my WPF Project is running under WCF data communication using LINQ. But the real thing is, i am not able to convert it into Web Based project. I tried to follow many tutorials but i could not convert my XAML based project to XBAP based project. I am using Visual Studio 10 Professional. Please can anyone guide me to solve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: These posts may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927688/wpf-switching-from-wpf-app-to-xbap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815461/dual-deploying-a-wpf-app-natively-and-as-a-xbap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646421/manual-xbap-publishing

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any shortcut for doing this, you will have to build a new XBAP application and reuse whatever possible. Although you can have a look at this article, its very old but may help you -

Converting EXE Projects to XBAPs:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/11/120718.html

Comment: Dear akjoshi,

Thank you for the reply.

i have already tried my luck from that given url but i was unable to solve my issue. I do not have that much time resource to re-develop the entire project in a new XBAP. If their is any other ideas please do share with me.